# Load multiple CSVs from google drive to create one GBQ table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 5 CSVs in a google drive folder. I have been able to upload a single csv to create a table, but I would like to upload all 5 files to create a single table.

Is this possible, and if so how would one go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use asterisc **"*"** to upload multiple files into one table.

[image]

Or you can use this **bq** command:

```
bq load --source_format=CSV --autodetect YOUR_DATASET_NAME.YOUR_DESTINATION_TABLE_NAME gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/YOUR-FILES-PREFIX-*.csv
```

Comment: More detailed here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table

Comment: The question asks about Google Drive, not Google Cloud Storage?